# Bloc external POST using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, security, web-applications

I need to block all External POST and allow POST only for specific folder or for  specific php files.

Comment: *"Please help me to cofigure my .htaccess correctly."* - Err... which one's that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to allow/deny post requests for spacific folders and files.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^POST\s/allowed_foloder/foo\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^POST\s/not_allowed_folder/foo.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply 
and for blocked POST how can they be allowed from specific adress (my website)